# Login directly through terminal to a new GNOME session passing user and password as input parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, gnome, login

I would like to know if there is any possibility to login directly to a new GNOME session without the need to put the login and password using automation tools like pyautogui, xdotool, uinput... (I say directly by terminal/command line) only passing the desired user and password as parameters and calling a new gnome session with Wayland and Xorg?

The only commands that I know are: `gnome-session --session gnome-wayland` to connect on Wayland and `gnome-session --session xorg` to do the same on Xorg but when I opened their man there aren't nothing about using additional parameters to connect.

My aim is reboot the system and start a new gnome session already passing an user and password. A mate here in my college suggested me to activate the automatic login (I don't know if there is a bash/terminal command for it or it can be only did through GUI) on the user which I desire to login and after login using  `su - <username>`